# Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I want to create a team foundation build to my company project, I have installed build controller and build agent on the server and then in visual studio I have created build definition but when I want run this build(Queue) I am getting this error

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: Could you give more info about which step exactly is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows Server 2008 R2, try installing this hotfix:

- [KB981898: A file does not download from an IIS 7.5 server that is
  running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981898)
- Blog post: [TFS unable to read
  data from the transport connection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylaf/archive/2010/02/10/team-foundation-server-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host.aspx)

This is a bug in http.sys that occurs when you try and download a large file over a relatively slow connection (3-4k/s).